# Star rating system

Tags: database, backend

I'm building an application as part of a course project which allows users to rate an place/event .

My basic question is how should I proceed in this ?
In what language should I write my code ?

If a user provides a 5-star rating, how do I collect it and put it in the database ?

Any guidelines on how to put the initial steps would be very helpful as my knowledge relating to web services is very weak.

Any help/pointers to more information would be very appreciated

Comment: this question is better suited to stackoverflow.com. However, you can get a star rating solution from polldaddy: http://polldaddy.com/features-ratings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is overly vague and isn't related to system administration, so it's probably going to get closed once someone comes along with the appropriate privileges.  However, as long as it's here...

> My basic question is how should I proceed in this ?

If you are completely at a loss you may want to spend some time consulting with your instructor, who may be able to suggest likely sources of information and provide some direction for your work.

> In what language should I write my code ?

You should write your code in a language with which you are familiar that allows you to fulfill the requirements of the project.  Anything else will needlessly extend the amount of time it takes to complete the project.  If your goal is to learn a new language, you face a mind-numbing number of choices.  Python, Ruby, and PHP are all see wide use in web applications. On Microsoft platforms, .NET is quite popular.  You will find proponents and detractors for all of them.

> If a user provides a 5-star rating, how do I collect it and put it in the database ?

This looks suspiciously like you're asking us to do your assignment for you.

Comment: If the O.P. didn't even get to the point of knowing there IS a language the app will be coded in, "Ask your teacher" was probably the only part of the answer the O.P. understood :(